# Class 'PLL_Links_' not found in /wp-content/plugins/polylang/include/model.php on line 915

Tags: wordpress, migration

After migration website on wordpress to another server and another domain.
I have website root in the same directory. I heard that there is some config in database of this plugin POLYLANG but have no idea where.
I have an error like:

> Class 'PLL_Links_' not found in /wp-content/plugins/polylang/include/model.php on line 915

someone has an idea how to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error, prior to the error was an "Undefined index" notice.
It was caused by an empty `$this->options['force_lang']` var.

This var is loaded from the `wp_options` table, the `option_name` within this table is `polylang`. There should be a JSON encoded array of `polylang` options.

In my case the issue could be fixed by removing the domains from the JSON data, so it reads something like:

```
"domains";a:0:{}
```

Answer (score 2):

This question can be still actual for some people.

I've spent tons of hours on it. And the trick that helped me is to fall back to v.0.9.8 from here - https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/advanced/.

Then get v.1.9.3 and unpack it to plugin folder. Then you are good to go with v.2+

Comment: I think the issue occurs when you try to change permalink settings right after installing polylang and before adding any languages.

Comment: actually for me it happened when I was migrating site. Polylang didn't migrate properly, and I had to setup/upgrade these versions.

Answer (score 1):

I got here because Polylang 2.3.1 was throwing a similar error after a database migration:

```
Class 'PLL_Links_' not found in /wp-content/plugins/polylang/include/model.php on line 560
```

If you look at the code in the model.php file referenced in the error, you can see that the plugin tries to retrieve a class name using the 'permalink_structure' option set in the database. If the migration changes this option to something Polylang can't handle, it triggers the error.

To go around the fatal error, you either have to:

- (re)move or rename the Polylang plugin folder, so that it does not trigger the error
- Set the Permalinks setting to default in WordPress Admin via *Options > Permalinks*
- reinstall Polylang (or remove/rename it) and reactivate it in the *Plugins* overview.

or

- manually delete the value for                                        'permalink_structure' in the `wp_options` table.

WordPress should run normally after this. I have not yet found out *why* it cannot handle certain permalink settings, but if I do, I'll update this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I did a global domain replacement in the file when moving the database from local to live . The problem in the end was that the serialized array in wp_option.option_name = "polylang" is broken. You must change strings length in the domain array:

```
wp_option.option_name = ...."domains";a:1: 
{s:2:"en";s:21:"http://example.local/";}....
```

on a local:

```
s:21:"http://example.local/";
```

after replacing in file:

```
s:21:"http://example.com/";
```

must be:

```
s:19:"http://example.com/";
```